# Copy value from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 spreadsheets.
In first spreadsheet, values are like this:

```
Column A   Column B  
AAA        Apple  
BBB        Bat   
CCC        Cricket
```

In the 2nd spreadsheet, values are:

```
Column A    Column B  
AAA         8/1/2015  
CCC         7/31/2015  
BBB         8/2/2015
```

I want to add another column (name it Column C) in 2nd spreadsheet which has the corresponding value of column A from the 1st spreadsheet.

IG, search for column A of 2nd spreadsheet in the 1st sheet, and, if text matches, add the column B value of 1st spreadsheet to column C in the 2nd spreadsheet.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your column representation didn,t follow well in the question. Put it as code and it will stay put. And also, your question will not get much sympathy if you did not try anything. What research have you done? What have you tried? Post it here to give us a starting point.

Comment: David, thanks for replying. I am not a developer, hence unable to add code. As for the question, I am not able to figure how to do it, hence posted the question here for help.

Comment: I did not mean to add code per se, but if you write your columns as if they were code (edit your question to make it like a block of code) the spaces you put will stay in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your sheets are named the default of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", the following formula will work:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

VLOOKUP will allow you to search a region for a specific value in the first column, and return the corresponding value from any column in the region.

Comment: swiehoff, Thanks. This works well when column A value are in order. 
What if Column A values from both sheets are not in order, and, values in 2nd sheet might have lesser values than 1st sheet? Like, for ex: 1st sheet 
Column A - AAA DDD VVV WWW ZZZ LLL
Column B - DDD AAA ZZZ

Comment: Using VLOOKUP for an exact search, as in my example, does not require that the values in the first column be in any specific order.  That formula would still work with the ID fields in the order you just listed.

Comment: @swiehoff, you might also want to look in to [Index/Match](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/)

Comment: I've used INDEX + MATCH before in situations where there were multiple criteria to consider.  In my opinion, for a simple case like this one, VLOOKUP is just easier to understand, though INDEX + MATCH certainly works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is with

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100=A1)*1, Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100)
```

This is great and can easily be used to search multiple criteria by replacing the `*1` with another search criteria like `(Sheet1!C1:C100=C1)` assuming you have something in the C column.